# Ember.js - App doesn't load all params from enviroment.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

My App is not loading all the parameters from the enviroment.js file, only the ones that are by default.

I install this package
[ember-g-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-g-recaptcha) and then you need to put a param in the config file.

The problem is that I create a demo app with ember-cli and I'ts working, but in my real app is not, maybe someone has any idea for why is not loading the params.

I try change the version of the modules in the **package.json**, but no luck, but I think is still over there the solution.

In my app the object of the config file throw this when you do this console log:

console.log(Ember.getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment'));

```
Object { 
  modulePrefix: "listings-search", 
  environment: "development", 
  rootURL: "/", 
  EmberENV: Object, 
  APP: Object, ember-cli-mirage: Object, exportApplicationGlobal: true
 }
```

In the demo app this is the result:

```
Object { 
   modulePrefix: "lala", 
   environment: "development", 
   rootURL: "/", 
   locationType: "auto", 
   gReCaptcha: Object, 
   EmberENV: Object, 
   APP: Object, ember-cli-mirage: Object, exportApplicationGlobal: true 
  }
```

This is my enviroment.js file

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'listings-search',
    environment: environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    gReCaptcha: {
      siteKey: 'asdasdads'
    },
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
    // ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    //   enabled: false
    // }
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Also when I try to access to my environment.js in this way that the official guide said in this [link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/configuring-ember/configuring-your-app/), throw this error in the console:

```
 Could not find module `/appname/config/environment` imported from `appname/components/name-component`
```

Version:

- ember: "~2.9.0"
- ember-cli: 2.14.0
- node: 8.2.0
- os: darwin x64

Comment: Which version of ember/ember-cli are you using?

Comment: ember-cli: 2.14.0
node: 8.2.0
os: darwin x64

Comment: Have you replaced 'appname' with the name of your app?

Comment: Yes, but that was not the problem, I have the solution, in a few minutes it will be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Ember.js inject the **Enviroment.js** file in a meta tag in the HTML, I didn't have any knowledge of this because the documentation does not say anything about this.

We are using a different strategy for the use of ember without the routes, so the meta-tag was harcoded in the code. I didn't see it (also I didn't pay attention to this, because i didn't know about the config params in the meta-tag)

Since Ember.js 2.3 we can set up in our broccoli file (**ember-cli-build.js**) the parameter `storeConfigInMeta: false` and the config file will be embedded in our javascript file.